# Prisma 1-1 relationship can't access data from both sides

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, relationship, one-to-one, prisma

So I have the following prisma schema setup in my `Nest` Project:

```js
model users {
    id                  Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
    uuid                String              @default(uuid())
    createdAt           DateTime            @default(now())
    updatedAt           DateTime            @updatedAt
    firstName           String
    authentication      authentications    @relation("Authentication", fields: [authenticationId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    authenticationId    Int
}

model authentications {
    id                          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    uuid                        String      @default(uuid())
    createdAt                   DateTime    @default(now())
    updatedAt                   DateTime    @updatedAt
    role                        Role        @default(USER)
    emailAddress                String      @unique
    password                    String
    isEmailConfirmed            Boolean     @default(false)
    currentHashedRefreshToken   String?
    user                        users?      @relation("Authentication")
}

enum Role {
  SUSPENSION    @map("SUSPENSION_ROLE")
  USER          @map("USER_ROLE")
  ADMIN         @map("ADMIN_ROLE")
}
```

Now I want to fetch the `users` from the Database. Therefor I call

```js
await this._prismaService.users.findMany({});
```

... it returns undefined.

But when I execute the same statement with `authentications` instead, it works.
Like so:

```js
await this._prismaService.authentications.findMany({});
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?
I just want to check if the user exists with a given UUID.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you get the expected results when you query your PostgreSQL table(s) using SQL statements in a tool like "pgAdmin4"?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe yes I get the expected results when I query the database directly. I used the IDE DataGrip from Jetbrains and this SQL Statement: SELECT * FROM authentication.users

Can it be possible that due to the 1-1 relationship, the query only works one sided from authentication? In my understanding it should work from both sides.

Comment: Difficult to tell... As a C# programmer I'd probably ask why you would use `findMany({})` when you are looking for a single user via primary key unique-row-identifier... But I'm not a `netjs` expert, so don't listen to the man in the corner.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I try findFirst() or findUnique(). It always returns undefined for users :(

Comment: It's hard to believe that `findMany()` returns undefined. It can't possibly do that because it's always returns an array. You probably have a typo somewhere or looking into wrong log statement.

Comment: You 're totally right. I messed something up in my Prisma middleware. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by double checking all my Prisma setup. After Danila's comment, I noticed that I did something wrong in my middleware that was causing the issue.